# How to make the dropdown on click not hover

Tags: javascript, menu, nav

I have code that makes my menu expand when the parent `li` is hovered over. I want to change it so that it only expands when it is clicked.
My code in CSS is:

```
 .nav li:hover li {
    /* Expanding the list elements */
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
}
```

How do I make this happen only when the parent is clicked?

My HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown" id="dropdownparent">
        <a href="#">Categories</a>
        <ul id="dropdown">
            <li id="dropdown"><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
            <li id="dropdown"><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
            <li id="dropdown"><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
            <li id="dropdown"><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the live page I am using to test this... http://portal.electrovision.co.uk/dropdown-test/

Comment: The live testing for this is here: http://portal.electrovision.co.uk/dropdown-test/

Comment: Unrelated to the question you're asking, but you should have exactly one instance of each HTML id. The multiple `id="dropdown"` instances is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

A slight css tweak

```
.nav li.open li {
    /* Expanding the list elements */
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
}
```

And some javascript (jQuery)

```
$('.nav > li.dropdown').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```